# Disable log ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, logging

Running Postgresql in a *better ask for forgiveness than permission* mode during the inserts.

Works great, only problem: The logs are flooded with the following message

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

Is there a possibility to explictly disable this log?

Comment: There is a hook, emit_log_hook, that should allow an extension to do what you want.  But I don't see any existing extensions which do it.  https://github.com/harukat/pg_truncate_log_message does something a bit different, but perhaps could serve as a good starting point if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

and check if a row was inserted or not.