# How to avoid errors in server log when conflict fails within a transaction before retry?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, unique-constraint, consistency

We have a table such as

```
create table pages (
  id uuid primary key not null,
  parent_id uuid not null references pages(id),
  shortname text not null,
  shorturl text not null,
  constraint globally_unique_shorturl unique (shorturl)
  constraint locally_unique_shortname unique (parent_id,shortname)
)
```

where the logical intent is to keep a collection of web pages where the full URL for each page is constructed from `shortname` fields defined by `parent_id` references. Root of the system points to itself with `parent_id`. As such, any given child must have unique shortname per parent (constraint locally_unique_shortname). In addition, we have globally unique shorturl (think `bit.ly`) that obviously must be globally unique for the whole table. The target is to keep both shortname and shorturl as short as possible and as such, we generate short random identifiers for shorturl. In addition, the shortname is selectable by user to allow system to create semantic URLs for every page.

When I'm trying to add a new page to the system (or modify existing page), we do it in a transaction and we create new `SAVEPOINT` immediately before trying to add a new page. If we get error

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 'XYZ'
```

we know that we need to rollback to savepoint and then figure out if `shorturl` or `shortname` should be modified before retrying. Note that if `shorturl` fails, we can generate a new one automatically, but if `shortname` fails, we need to prompt user for a new value, so we really need to know which constraint failed. (In addition, this query fails pretty seldom so I'd prefer not having to try `SELECT` with the new value to figure out if it's already taken because this mostly succeeds without any extra queries. Also note that such `SELECT` would still race against other concurrent transactions and I'd still end up with the same issue every now and then.) We're using serializable transactions, in case it makes a difference.

However, this causes PostgreSQL to always store this error in the server log even when the code obviously handles this correctly (rollback is emitted immediately the query fails). These errors spam the log to make other possible *real* problems harder to notice. Obviously, I can just fall back to filtering the log before trying to monitor it, but *that* would feel pretty poor solution.

To workaround this, [Disable log ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/246302/29183) suggests that I should use syntax `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`. This would be otherwise fine (I could try to do insert and if no rows were affected I can assume that I have a conflict and nothing will be added to server log) **but** I'm missing info about which constraint failed when there are multiple possible constraints.

**Is there any nice way to solve this without having to modify source code of PostgreSQL or load some custom extension in PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 1):

You have two unique constraints, and you say that the one on `shortname` causes an error only rarely.

So use

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ON (shorturl) DO NOTHING;
```

Then check if you got an error and how many rows were inserted.

- if you got an error, prompt the user for a new `shortname`
- if no row was inserted, generate a new `shorturl`

Then you will only get error messages about duplicate `shortname`s in your log, which should reduce the log spam to a level that is not bothersome.

Comment: Pretty nice solution for this case! This wouldn't scale up to 3 or more constraints so I will not mark it as accepted. Even though the example in question only gave 2 constraints, I'm hoping to come up with generic solution.

Comment: I think that solution would be to generate names so that collisions are unlikely, for example using a hash.

Comment: Due birthday paradox, you need to use much longer hashes than strictly necessary if unique value is all you need. When you target short identifiers, you'll get collisions every now and then unless you have single serialized source for the identifiers.

Comment: What's wrong with a database sequence?

Comment: If you mean `serial` type, it's not supported with "logical replication". In addition, for our case we do not want to use identifiers that leak info about creation order.

Comment: You could hash the sequence value: `md5(nextval('seq'))`. That presents no problem at all with logical replication.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood something, if you run code like `insert into ... values (md5(nextval('seq')), ...)` logical replication is going to run function `md5(nextval('seq'))` on every server and each will end up with different value. Yes, if you compute hash outside SQL and simply store hash as opaque id on the SQL level, it obviously works. Until your hash collides with sequence numbers, too. If you try that in practice (say take 6 first characters from SHA-256 output as a string) you'll find that it will collide after about 2^(8*6/2) instead of 2^(8*6) ids due birthday paradox.

Comment: You misunderstand. Logical replication does **not** replicate the statement, but the resulting string. Try it! Use longer strings to reduce the odds of collision.

Comment: Yes, I had misunderstood the problem with serial fields. Reading the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/logical-replication-restrictions.html tells me that the problem is not the result of `nextval()` if you use just one master server. However, in master-master configuration with logical replication, different master servers may generate same value for `nextval()`. In my opinion, it's simpler to use UUID for everything instead of trying to use serial fields.

Comment: ... but we are talking about generating a random string here, not multi-master replication. You need the sequence only on the master server.